# Use output in select statement

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have a case where I have to choose 100 columns out of 240 columns in select statement for that I have used below query to get those 100 column but couldn't use them in select statement

Query:

```
select listagg(column_name,',') within group (order by column_name) as col_name
from all_tab_cols
where lower(column_name) like 'test%'
```

Result:

```
col_name
-----------------------------    
test1,test2,test3,....test100
```

Expected output:

use those resulted values in select statement

```
select test1,test2,test3.... test100 
from table;
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: ... select 'select from ' || listagg(column_name,',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY column_name) || ' from table' as qry ... did You mean this? Then use the output of query in next query. E.g. using execute immediate.

Comment: Thank you, yes I'm expecting the same but don't know how to use execute immediate

Comment: Well, there is certainly some app you want to run this from. So use your query, build your final query string from its result and execute it. Where is the problem in that?

Answer (score 1):

Dynamic query is what you wanted here. You can use below two query inside Stored Procedure or Functions.

```
select listagg(column_name,',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY column_name) as col_name INTO VAR_COL_DETAILS   
from all_tab_cols    
where lower(column_name) like 'test%'

execute IMMIDEATE 'SELECT '||VAR_COL_DETAILS|| 'FROM TABLE_NAME';
```

Comment: Thank you, but got an error while executing above query
Error : missing keyword

Comment: I have used below procedure, but ended up with errors,

create procedure test_col

declare @VAR_COL_DETAILS; 

begin

select listagg(column_name,',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY column_name) as col_name INTO @VAR_COL_DETAILS   
from all_tab_cols    
where lower(column_name) like 'test%'

execute IMMIDEATE 'SELECT '||VAR_COL_DETAILS|| 'FROM TABLE_NAME';    

end ;

Comment: you need to use this query to output as cursor or string.. that depends on you. And the error message is because of missing semi colon(;) after 'test%'.

Comment: you are using mysql or Oracle?

Comment: I'm using Oracle